# Select random value from Pandas dataframe, present it to the user, and then delete that value from the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

One of my nicer problems in life is that I have a bunch of duplicate Steam keys on hand, whether they're from Humble Bundles or friends or otherwise. I want to build a program that reads a list of keys, spits out a random key from the list, and then deletes it from the list.

So far, I'm able to pull in my keys from a CSV, save it to a dataframe, and pull out a random key

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('./testCSV.csv')

randomKey = df.sample()
print(randomKey['Key'])
```

`df` yields the following dataframe

|  | Product | Key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Game 1 | abcd-efgh-jklm |
| 1 | Game 2 | da34-2444-1654 |
| 2 | Game 3 | 0001-5133-0911 |
| 3 | Game 4 | 9fj1-2812-vvvv |
| 4 | Game 5 | nvow-meow-uhuh |
| 5 | Game 6 | 9302-ca3f-0000 |
| 6 | Game 7 | amjk-un93-cuup |
| 7 | Game 8 | fork-spon-knif |
| 8 | Game 9 | 091w-iffo-cmww |
| 9 | Game 10 | p992-1ccc-cppl |

Printing `randomKey` prints a random cell like so:

```
  Product             Key
5  Game 6  9302-ca3f-0000
```

...and `print(randomKey['Key'])` yields the following

```
5    9302-ca3f-0000
Name: Key, dtype: object
```

There's a few things I want to do.

- I want to print just the key from `randomKey` without the index or product name printed alongside it.
- I also want to permanently remove the `randomKey` from `df` after it is displayed to the user.
- As a sort of failsafe, I want to add `randomKey` to a new dataframe to keep track of past keys that have been pulled from `df`.

I'm also doing all of this in Python with Pandas, so if anyone has recommendations for other libraries or resources that could make this process easier or more efficient, please share.

Comment: ... and concerning your first question: if you type type(randomKey['Key']), you'll see that this is still a series (pandas.core.series.Series). You can get your "pure" randomKey (i.e. the string), quite simply by, e.g., appending a [0] (randomKey['Key'][0]).

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it for you:

```
# create example dataframe
df = pd.read_html("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73733987/select-random-value-from-pandas-dataframe-present-it-to-the-user-and-then-dele")[0]

# create new dataframe
new_df = pd.DataFrame()

while not df.empty:
    key = df.sample()                    # sample random key
    new_df = pd.concat([new_df, key])    # add key to new df
    df = df.drop(index=key.index)        # remove key from old df 
    print(key.Key.values[0])             # print only key
```

**Output**:
[image]